# Is there a listing for direct red-eye flights from the west-coast to the east-coast in the US?

Tags: usa, los-angeles, boston

I am exploring possibilities to get from Los Angeles to Boston. So far I have only found flights arriving before midnight and including a long layovers (4-6 hours) some where in between. Since I am a bit flexible, I could consider other airports near LAX and BOS. Is there a listing for direct red-eye flights in the US?

Comment: A quick search throws up Delta, Virgin America and Jetblue red-eye direct flights from LAX to BOS - what's wrong with any of those?

Comment: @gagravarr Nothing, other that they didn't show in the search engines I used.

Comment: @andra What were the search engines?

Comment: @choster rome2rio, klm, airfrance, lufthansa. But I actually search for a multi destination trip. That is flying to the west coast, back the east coast and then back home. Apparently that is not the way to go. Unfortunatly, searching delta doesn't allow to include airrail. I simply wanted to much and I should consider the trips on individual accounts

Comment: @andra Interesting. Perhaps the European airline searches only return codeshares, and the codeshares for the redeyes may be more expensive or sold out and thus get excluded from the results. The US-based search engines like Kayak, Orbitz, Priceline, and Expedia find plenty of overnight flights.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there will be such a website, as there are so many flights, and they change seasonally.

I've just done a quick search on the ITA Matrix, for direct flights from LAX to BOS on a random Friday a few weeks hence, direct flights only, leaving after 9pm:

[image: Flights]

Excluding code shares, that's 5 different overnight direct redeye flights from LAX to Boston to select from!

Comment: Great! Strangely the delta flights didn't show in the sky team affiliate I used to search.

Answer (score 1):

It has been 4 years now, and more options have emerged over the time. I’m answering hope it will help other travelers on the route. Nowadays, travelers can avoid layover with nonstop red eye flights with JetBlue (B6) and Alaska Airlines (AS). United (UA) and American (AA) also operate nonstop flights.
[image]

Check this page listing some best nonstop as well as connecting [red eye flight options](https://www.cheapfaremart.com/flights/cheap-red-eye-flight-deals). You may also run a new search to get one as per your convenience.
From ONT, a nearby airport (40 miles from Los Angeles), you can also find options.